# Flutter - Android Native Platform Integration

Tags: flutter

When an external component such as a Camera or File picker is needed, the Flutter for Android Developers documentation (currently in the works) states that we would have to build a **native platform integration**.

I currently have a device that has a built-in barcode reader with a  manufacturer-provided Android API. So, for that I would need to pursue this native platform integration method - or even for playing videos or using the camera for that matter I would think.

Is there an example repo that demonstrates how a well-integrated app should be? ..a project that integrated ExoPlayer for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use platform channels to call native APIs that aren't exposed by the Flutter platform.

There is an example in the [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) docs:

> The full, runnable source-code for this example is available in [/examples/platform_channel/](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel) for Android with Java and iOS with Objective-C.

If you want to make your code reusable by others, you can publish it as a package, but this is optional. There is a [repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins) of plugins maintained by the Flutter team that you can use for inspiration.